# Understanding a proof of Gauss-Lucas theorem algebraicly

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

According to [a proof of Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem) from wikipedia, a logarithmic derivative of polynomial $P(z)$ is
$$\frac{P^{\prime}(z)}{P(z)} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{z - z_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\overline{z} - \overline{z}_i}{|z - z_i|^2}.$$
Here $P(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial with $z_i$ to be the zeros of $P(z)$. If $P^{\prime}(z) = 0$ and $P(z) \neq 0$, then
$$z\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}z_i.$$
Up until here, I do understand what is going on. However, I'm not following what happens next.

According to Wikipedia, "$z$ is a weighted sum with positive coefficients that sum to one, or the barycenter on affine coordinates, of the complex numbers $z_{i}$ (with different mass assigned on each root whose weights collectively sum to $1$)". I do not understand what this sentence means. How come that the weights collectively sum to 1?

Let $$m_i = \frac{1}{|z-z_i|^2}$$ and $$m = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{m_i}.$$
Why would
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{m_i}{m} = 1?$$
If that is the case, then I can see why $z$ lies in the convex hull of the zeros of $P$. I feel like it has something to do with normalization, but I must say that I completely don't see it.

Comment: note that here $m$ (the coefficient of $z$) is actually $=\sum m_i$ (where $m_i$ are the coefficients of $z_i$) so trivially $\sum m_i/m =1$

Comment: But $1/{m_i} = |z - z_i|^2 \neq m_i$

Comment: your equation is $z\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}z_i$ or $mz=\sum m_iz_i$ with $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}\right) =m=\sum m_i$; not sure what is the problem

Comment: $$m = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{m_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac{1}{|z-z_n|^2}}= \sum_{i=1}^n|z - z_n|^2.$$ But $$m_i = \frac{1}{|z - z_n|^2}.$$ So $$m = \sum_{i=1}^n |z -z_i|^2 \neq \sum m_i = \sum\frac{1}{|z-z_n|^2}  $$, right?

Comment: no, you are wrong and you misunderstand $m=\sum m_i$ - just read what you wrote in the OP second equation - $m$ is the coefficient of $z$ since the whole point of this proof is to express $z=a_1z_1+..a_nz_n, a_1,..a_n \ge 0, \sum a_k =1$ and we realize that precisely by writing $z=\sum (m_i/m) z_i$

Comment: If I was wrong could you please pinpoint the mistake in my previous comment. Because I also don't see what you mean. I write there $m_i = 1/|z - z_i|$. So why would $m = \sum m_i$ if I define my $m$ as $m = \sum 1/m_i$? Using the things that I wrote, we should have $m = \sum |z - z_i|^2$. This is definitely not equal to sum of $m_i$ I define.

Comment: I posted an answer to show how Gauss-Lucas follows from your second equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per comments, we use the second equation above to show that it immediately implies that $z$ is a convex combination of the $z_i$. In the OP we have the following:

"Here $P(z)$ is a non-constant polynomial with $z_i$ to be the zeros of $P(z)$. If $P^{\prime}(z) = 0$ and $P(z) \neq 0$, then
$$z\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}z_i.$$

Looking at the equation above we denote by $m$ the coefficient of $z$ and by $m_i$ the coefficient of $z_i, i=1,..n$, so the equation is:

$mz =\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_iz_i$ or equivalently $z=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{m_i}{m}z_i=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_iz_i$ where $\alpha_i=m_i/m$

Now we claim that $\alpha_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=1$ which means precisely that $z$ satisfies the definition of being in the convex hull of the $z_i$.

But notice that $m=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}$ while $m_i=\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}$ so it is self-evident that $m=\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i$ hence $ \sum_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_i=1$ while it is also immediate that $0 \le \alpha_i \le 1$ by their defintion, so we are done and Gauss-Lucas has been proved

Comment: First of a=ll I notice that you use a different definition of $m$ and $m_i$ that I define. Anyhow I'll just work with your definition. But then why $z = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{m_i}{m}z_i$ Using your definition, we get $$z = \frac{\sum \frac{z_i}{|z-z_i|^2}}{\sum \frac{1}{|z-z_i|^2}}$$

Comment: the denominator is $m$ and the numerator is $m_iz_i$ since $m_i=\frac{1}{|z - z_i|^2}$, so the sum is $(\sum m_iz_i)/m=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{m_i}{m}z_i$

Answer (score 0):

This means that the coefficients form a convex combination, that is, each coefficient is smaller than one in modules and the sum of these coefficients is exactly one.

Comment: But how do I check in the proof that the sum is indeed 1?